# Leaflet.js Fullscreen API not working in Webkit

Tags: webkit, fullscreen, leaflet

While working on the Site http://www.bikemap.net/en/ I wanted to fix a Issue concerning the fullscreen mode of the map. When clicking the Button it results in a full black screen in webkit Browsers. Works correctly in Firefox.
Does anyone experienced a similar issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It took me days to figure out what the problem was. In my case it was that the `<div>` I wanted to make fullscreen hat the following CSS set:

```
#mydiv {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Some if you set your width to auto WebKit makes it 0 pixels wide in full screen mode! I **removed** the `auto` and now everything works fine!

Hope this helps,
Anton